# How to invoke a custom tag in servlet or inside another tag?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I want to call dynamic tag in my custom tag .
for example

```
<mytag:taga attribute="showtag" value="helo">
</mytag>
```

---

showtag is another custom tag.

the main idea is call another tag by name inside my tag

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass in the output of one tag as an attribute into your tag, like this:

```
<mytag:tag simpleParam="asfasdf">
   <jsp:attribute name="complexParam">
     <xx:SomeCrazyTag/>
   </jsp:attribute>
</mytag:tag>
```

i guess that only gets you part of the way there, because you want to dynamically invoke any tag inside of your tag.

why would you want to do this?

anyway, for a better answer you will have to look at the tag lifecycle, and figure out how to instantiate a tag inside of your tag, pass it all the correct stuff etc just like the container would. If you are doing it that way, then **you are probably doing it wrong**

Comment: or I should use jsp fragment?